# How to disable spring joint in unity 3d

Tags: unity

How can I disable Spring joint in unity 3d, since disabling feature only available in 2d mode, I am not able to find any way to disable it via script

Comment: Have you tried disabling the rigidbody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/enable-disable-a-joint.24525/) on Unity forums, there's no way to disable a [spring joint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpringJoint.html) other than to break it and re-connect it. Quoting from the forum thread in Unity:

> I was able to create a
>   JointToggler component that finds a joint on the same object and
>   connects/disconnects the connectedBody rigidbody when it is
>   enabled/disabled (like Joints should do by default).

This is the relevant code supplied in the quoted post:
    using UnityEngine;

```
public class JointToggler : MonoBehaviour
{
   [SerializeField] private Joint joint;
   private Rigidbody connectedBody;

   private void Awake()
   {
       joint = joint ? joint : GetComponent<Joint>();
       if (joint) connectedBody = joint.connectedBody;
       else Debug.LogError("No joint found.", this);
   }

   private void OnEnable() { joint.connectedBody = connectedBody; }

   private void OnDisable()
   {
       joint.connectedBody = null;
       connectedBody.WakeUp();
   }
}
```

I'd normally downvote a question like this for lack of research, since the first google result of `disable spring joint unity` gave me what I needed, but I couldn't find anything like the sort here, so I'm putting this answer here for archiving purposes.

Comment: That's not really correct (anymore?) ... from [`Joint.connectedBody`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Joint-connectedBody.html) -> `A reference to another rigidbody this joint connects to. If not set then the joint connects the object to a fixed point in world space.`